# File memory leak in C

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I have this simple code for writing to a file in c

```
FILE*  fp = fopen ("file.txt", "w+");
fprintf(fp, "bla");
free(fp);
```

i'm getting tons of errors when running valgrind,

```
 Address "xxxxxxx" is 192 bytes inside a block of size 568 free'd
 Address "xxxxxxx" is 168 bytes inside a block of size 568 free'd
```

and a lot more like these.
No leaks!, but errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should replace free(fp) with fclose(fp).
Also check fp for NULL

Answer (score 2):

`fopen` must be paired with `fclose`:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("file.txt", "w+");
if (fp) {
  // ...
  if (0 != fclose(fp)) {
    // error when closing the file; data may be lost
  }
} else {
  // could not open file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Closing a file opened with [fopen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) requires a call to [fclose](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fclose). Calling [free](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) on a [FILE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io)* is *undefined behavior*.

The valgrind errors are telling you, that the address you are trying to `free` is **inside** a block of allocated memory. In general, you can only `free` an entire block of memory allocated with `malloc`, so you have to provide an address to the start of the block.